# Creating a cube opening animation

Tags: css, css-animations, css-shapes, css-transforms

I have the following HTML and CSS code to draw the top of a cube. So it moves down and I want it to animate as if it is opening up. I am unable to figure out how to transform the top so that it appears to open up.

I have included the entire code for the cube. With respect to this, I want the top to open up.

```css
.pers500 {
  perspective: 500px;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  -moz-perspective: 500px;
}
/* Define the container div, the cube div, and a generic face */

.container {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  border: none;
  animation-name: moveDown;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform: translate(0px, 110px);
}
.cube {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  perspective-origin: 150% 150%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 150% 150%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.face {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Define each face based on direction */

.front {
  width: 3.64em;
  height: 3.43em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
  transform: translateZ(50px) translateX(171px) translateY(222px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px) translateX(171px) translateY(222px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(50px) translateX(171px) translateY(222px);
}
.left {
  width: 2em;
  height: 3.4em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 70px;
  transform: skewY(40deg) translateZ(50px);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(40deg) translateZ(50px) translateY(65px) translateX(-20px);
  -moz-transform: skewY(40deg) translateZ(50px) translateY(62px) translateX(-20px);
}
.top {
  width: 3.65em;
  height: 1.7em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin: 100px;
  transform: skewX(50deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(-14px) translateY(20px);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(50deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(-14px) translateY(20px);
  ;
  -moz-transform: skewX(50deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(-14px) translateY(20px);
  ;
  animation-name: openTop;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0px, 55px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, 110px);
  }
}
@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0px, 55px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, 110px);
  }
}
@keyframes openTop {
  /*0% {transform:rotateX(30deg);}
 50% {transform:rotateX(30deg);}
 100% {transform:rotateX(30deg);} commented code here doesn't work*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube pers500">
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <div class="face top"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="face left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opening, in the sense? Do you have a sample like how it should happen or comparison?

Comment: Please read: [mcve] | What have you tried? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the cube open up, you first need to set the `transform-origin` property (as mentioned in the other answer) to `top`. This setting would make the top side of the `.face.top` remain fixed when the rotation is being performed. Then you need to add the rotation using `rotateX()`. This would rotate the top face to produce the opening effect. Note that the `transform` property should contain the entire list of transforms for it to open correctly. You cannot just add the `rotateX()` alone within the animation.

```css
.pers500 {
  perspective: 500px;
}
/* Define the container div, the cube div, and a generic face */

.container {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  border: none;
  animation-name: moveDown;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform: translate(0px, 110px);
}
.cube {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  perspective-origin: 150% 150%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.face {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid brown; /* just for testing */
}
/* Define each face based on direction */

.front {
  width: 3.64em;
  height: 3.43em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
  transform: translateZ(50px) translateX(171px) translateY(222px);
}
.left {
  width: 2em;
  height: 3.43em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 70px;
  transform: skewY(40deg) translateZ(50px) translateY(64px) translateX(-20px);
}
.top {
  width: 3.65em;
  height: 1.69em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin: 100px;
  transform: skewX(50deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(-74px) translateY(20px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  animation-name: openTop;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0px, 55px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, 110px);
  }
}
@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0px, 55px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, 110px);
  }
}
@keyframes openTop {
  0% {
    transform: skewX(50deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(-74px) translateY(20px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewX(50deg) translateZ(50px) translateX(-74px) translateY(20px) rotateX(200deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube pers500">
    <div class="face front"></div>
    <div class="face top"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="face left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

- Setting a `transform-origin` will affect the position of the top face in the demo and so the values that you've used for `translateX()` and `translateY()` on the top face need to be modified a bit like in the above demo.
- The vendor prefixed versions of properties should always be added before the standard property in order to be future proof.
- I have removed the vendor prefixed versions in the above snippet just to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Set the transform origin to tbe edge of the cube with

```
transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
```

Then rotate it around the z axis:

```
transform: rotateZ(90deg);
```

I hope this works for you, I didn't have the chance to test it.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't